# How to get a record from an Entity using Linq expression

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I could not find exact answer for what I need, so I posted probably answered questions for other situations.

I have an Entity that has all the Applications' names and ids. I need to get the ID  of a specific application.

That's what I do:

```
string applicationName = (string)settingsReader.GetValue("ApplicationName", typeof(String));

int ApplicationID = GetUser.User.Applications.Where(app => app.ApplicationName == applicationName).Select(a => a.ApplicationID);
```

However, I'm getting an error saying `"Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable<int>' to '<int>'"`

How can I do something like that?

Comment: `.Select(...)` gives you an `IEnumerable<int>`, not a single value. I assume you want to add `.Single()` on the end of that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you will always get a result (and if you use `Single` that better be true), you can just use

```
int ApplicationID = GetUser.User.Applications.Single(app => app.ApplicationName == applicationName).ApplicationID;
```